# R dplyr: group_by and slice based on two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am trying to keep the most recent row from a df, based on two different column values.
The dataset I try to analyse looks like:
input:

```
name     indicator  year  value
Roma     av_income  2008  23
Roma     av_income  2010  24
Roma     unemp      2009  7.6
Bologna  av_income  2008  19
Bologna  av_income  2010  21
Firenze  unemp      2011  9.2
```

Desired output:

```
name     indicator  year  value
Roma     av_income  2010  24
Roma     unemp      2009  7.6
Bologna  av_income  2010  21
Firenze  unemp      2011  9.2
```

I am using a short dplyr code which filters for either name or indicator, but in the current state it obviously deletes either relevant city names or indicators. Any hints on how I slice with a grouping both by indicator and by name?

```
cities <- cities %>%
  group_by(indicator) %>%
  slice(which.max(year))
write.csv(x = india, file)
```

Thank you!

Comment: group_by(name, indicator) ?

Comment: Oh, this actually works. Stupid me, wonder why I had missed that. Thank you a lot, AntoniosK!

Comment: You can also use `filter(year == max(year))` instead of `slice(...)`

Comment: Ah thank you. I am just learning dplyr, so this is all useful!